# Odd behavior in edit history when I edited my deleted answer

Tags: support, edits, voting

Question in question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956654/241536

Here is a timeline of events.

1. I answered a question.  I missread a key part of the OP, and hence provided and incorrect answer.
2. Another user (hvd) commented on what I missed.
3. I commented back, "Oops" and deleted the post.
4. I edited the deleted post and undeleted it.
5. At this point I noticed that there was a single DV on my post, which I assume was entered by hvd at the time of their comment.
6. hvd later commented that they couldn't revert their downvote even though I had obviously edited.
7. When I look at the edit history of my answer, there is no indication whatsoever that I edited the post.  As far as the log in concerned, the edited version is the original.  I'm guessing this is why hvd couldn't revert.

I'm not concerned about the rep.  What concerns me is the edit history.  Why does it not show my original post along with the edits I made?

Note that a third user (Lightness) subsequently edited my post several minutes after this all took place.

Comment: You edited in the 5 minute grace period. Since any edit within the 5 minute window does not result in a history entry, the downvote cannot be undone either. Just create a new edit outside of the 5-minute window.

Comment: Did you do delete/edit in first five minutes ? if so then you will not get the edit history

Comment: You have 50K and do not know about the editing grace period? I am baffled...

Comment: That must be it.  I have edited hundreds or thousands of posts and answers and never knew about that 5-minute grace.

Comment: @qwertynl:  Correct.  Don't be baffled.  I had never noticed it's effects before.

Comment: Darn those people who earn reputation through knowledge of content and not hyper-popular poll questions, sockpuppets or floods of mediocre suggested edits!

Comment: @Pops: Represent!